# when I return the address of a static var in a function, the address is not correct

Tags: c, memory

```
ProtobufCAllocator *kvs_pb_allocator()
{
    static ProtobufCAllocator allocator;
    //do something here

    return &allocator; //print the address, it is 0x2aaaaafc12c0
}
```

In another program call this function (from a different file):

```
ProtobufCAllocator *alloctor = kvs_pb_allocator(); 
//print the address, it is 0xffffffffaafc12c0
```

Why did this problem happen? The other daemon program I wrote works fine. Just in this situation it prints the wrong value.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. I suspect the issue is elsewhere. But two different *programs* have different addresses for their static variables.

Comment: linux x86_64. the function define and call program segment are in different files.

Comment: I use gdb to debug, meet this problem.

Comment: Looks like 0x2aaaaafc12c0 is downcasted to 32 bit and again sign extended to 64 Bit. Is it possible to work with the pointer outside? Looks broken to me.

Comment: You should take a look to the generated machins code ;).

Comment: :) this is hard to look the machins code for me. I try again. when i put the func definition and the call program segment in one file, they work OK.

Comment: Did you declare the function in the file you called it from. If not, the compiler will assume that it returns an int, your code will extend the int to a pointer.

Answer (score 7):

You're on a 64-bit machine and didn't use a type-safe mechanism for printing the address in the second location.  The value got chopped to 32-bits, then sign-extended to 64 bits.

```
0x00002aaa_aafc12c0
0xffffffff_aafc12c0
```

where the underscore indicates the 32-bit boundary in the middle of the values.  The trouble is more likely in the way you're printing the value than in the value itself.

You can verify this by printing the address more carefully.  You could use:

```
printf("Address: %p\n", (void *)alloctor);
```

since this is C.

---

I assume (perhaps without justification) that you do have a header that declares the function `kvs_pb_allocator()` and that the header is used both in the file where you define the function and in the file where you call it.  If not, then get into the discipline of ensuring that all functions are declared (or defined if they are static functions) before they are used.  All external functions should be declared in a header.  All code that references a given function should use the single header that declares that function.  This is necessary in C99 and C2011; you should impose the discipline upon yourself if you're stuck with a C89 compiler.

If you use GCC, you can use:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition
```

to get the warnings. Your code would get a warning for an old-style definition because you should define:

```
ProtobufCAllocator *kvs_pb_allocator(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, and with *C* the good way to print a pointer is to use `%p` in the `printf` format string, and to cast the pointer to `(void*)` in the `printf` argument.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: agreed — so I added it to my answer while you added the comment.

Comment: And if the original poster had compiled with `gcc -Wall -g` the compiler would probably have warned about such mistakes.

Comment: Lindydancer give the solution, I did't declare the function in the file. Running in 32bit OS it's ok, while 64bit OS is wrong.

Comment: the 'print' in my question i mean using gdb to debug the program, not really using 'printf()' :) Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the function in the file you called it from. If not, the compiler will assume that it returns an int, your code will extend the int to a pointer.